# Traceroute doesn't reach gateway

Tags: linux, ipv4, gateway, networking

I have problem with my [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) 11.3 network. So, I've assigned IP address 192.168.137.2 to it, and another computer (Windows 7) with IP address 192.168.137.1.

On the openSUSE, the gateway is the 192.168.137.1. and the ping result is

```
ping 192.168.137.1

PING 192.168.137.1 (192.168.137.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.53 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.437 ms
^C
--- 192.168.137.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.437/1.487/2.537/1.050 ms
```

And the routing is:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

but, what the problem is,

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets using UDP
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 .
 .
 .
30  * * *
```

Why does the traceroute not even reach the gateway? Or maybe, this is the networking rule I missed somehow.

Comment: How about `traceroute -I 8.8.8.8`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason probably is that the Windows 7 internal firewall filters some kinds of packets. Try to disable firewall in Win7 for a while. Use GUI Control Panel or start CLI window as an administrator and issue command

```
netsh firewall set opmode disable
```

Now repeat traceroute test. In case of positive response from your gateway 192.168.137.1 your next step must be to re-enable Win7 firewall

```
netsh firewall set opmode enable
```

and change its setting to allow the trace.

If problem persist with disabled W7 firewall you should check local firewall in OpenSUSE PC.
Next command flushes all firewall rules and enables totally open communication till next reboot:

```
iptables -F *
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the UDP packets are being filtered. Try `tcptraceroute`.

Comment: sorry but, `tcptraceroute: command not found` any other options aside from installing it?? the linux doesn't have internet, yet.

Comment: @Lee You're trying to do a `traceroute` without an internet connection?

Comment: try "traceroute -T"

Comment: @Shawn, he should still be able to trace within his local network.

Comment: @shawn, well yes. i'm trying to give it internet connection. the 192.168.137.1 (the one im using) has internet. that's why, i'm trying to share it.

Comment: Sharing internet on Win7 can be tricky. Did you enable connection sharing on the Win7 machine? [Using ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing)

Comment: aside from whether the internet can be shared, i think the problem here is, why does the traceroute for 8.8.8.8 (ok, this is something belongs to google) don't even reach the gateway. @skjaidev, the `traceroute -T` doesn't work too.

Comment: @transistor1, yes it's enabled. how can i be sure? get the conenction properties, and checked the `allow other network user to connect....` under the `sharing` tab

Comment: @shawn, yes. the firewall is also Off.

Comment: Does the Win7 machine have a built-in crossover or are you using a crossover cable? Also, where did those other routes come from? 10.1.1.0  and 169.254.0.0. Perhaps you should try deleting those and work on the internet connectivity first. Unless they are allocated in /etc/network/interfaces I think `ifdown eth0` and then `ifup eth0` should clear them.

Comment: @transistor1, deleted as you said, doesn't work either.

Comment: @transistor1, it WORKED with a little `/etc/init.d/network restart`

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Cool! Restarting network or just the interface often helps.

Comment: You figured it out yourself... but always glad to help when i can!